# Google sheets query plus import range?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

i am trying to import columns HDCB from sheet 1 to columns ABCD where column 9 in sheet 1 = PPE

tried the oold query plus import range but it wont work. formula is in sheet 2 ppe details column 1 row 33820

sheet attached below
Sheet 1

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1_yXPDJxSbuK_MERyWfAbS1Fk6YwtSZ0GjN5GZSDSJrk/edit#gid=0

Sheet 2

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/u/2/d/1ERDU2W2rxnyI3d-yMtJzPGaYT-DZF6pH/htmlview#gid=131153001

Comment: sheet2 is in xlsx format, and we can access to formalas, pls share a spreadsheet

Answer (score 0):

Since column I contains numbers and text, you can't select Col9='PPE' directly, you will have to transform all the column in text.

```
=QUERY({importrange("1_yXPDJxSbuK_MERyWfAbS1Fk6YwtSZ0GjN5GZSDSJrk","importdata!A1:H"),arrayformula(to_text(importrange("1_yXPDJxSbuK_MERyWfAbS1Fk6YwtSZ0GjN5GZSDSJrk","importdata!I1:I")))},"select Col8,Col4,Col3,Col2 where Col9='PPE' ")
```

[image]

Comment: @ankitgupta : did you test it ?